# Turn on print, stderr, or stdout by tag during test run in Behave Python

Tags: python, bdd, behave

So I am trying to implement an `@warn` tag. The idea is this test doesn't make an assertion and fail, but instead simply prints out a warning. I see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150404/how-can-i-see-print-statements-in-behave-bdd/28551235#28551235), but that only explains how to do it on command line or in Behave.ini file, but I don't want to turn it on for all tests, just ones tagged warn. I tried this in my environment file but with no success:

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    if 'warn' in context.tags:
        # Set to immediately out rather than keep for fail
        stdout_capture = False
        stderr_capture = False

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    if 'warn' in context.tags:
        stdout_capture = True
        stderr_capture = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify the context, not just create a variable with that name.  Unfortunately, even `context.stdout_capture = sys.__stdout__` 
doesn't seem to solve this.  It generates a ContextMaskWarning as you are modifying something that behave will, and does, overwrite.  Of course you could modify your instance behave to avoid this.